# Altium keypad footprints custom pad DRC errors

Tags: altium, footprint

[image]

I've created a rubber keypad switch footprints which is a simple contact pad design. First I used arcs and tracks to get a outline and then converted them to top copper region (two separate regions). And then placed a pad on the end of each contact.

Overall the design looks flawless while editing in libraries but when I used it in the schematics then I have come across DRC errors saying there is a short circuit within Top Copper Region and Pads. This is visually true but on the practical side only the Pad will be used to connect the traces.

What's wrong with it, and do I how to overcome such violations (especially in keypad contacts design)?

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have ver 17.1.9

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/((Working+with+Custom+Pad+Shapes))_AD) should cover it. Older versions were not as nice, IIRC.